# Access with personal account to multi-tenant application AAD

Tags: ruby, azure, oauth-2.0

I have multi-tenant application and I would like all users of all types could access my application.

I have read that AAD API version 2.0 have possibility to access all types of account, i.e. work, school, guest, personal (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison). 
So I am making request on v2.0 endpoint with ruby lang. Here is my url:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=some_id&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauthorize&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access`

When I try to login with my personal creds it says 
'This doesn't look like a work or school email. You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead.'

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where did you register the app? I'm guessing the app is a v1 app. Please see this guide for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app.

Comment: I have read this article twice, but I do not see reference v1 or v2 app. I just see single tenant and multi tenant application.

Comment: That's odd.. You registered it in Azure portal? There's no such thing as v1 and v2 app by the way. All support both.

Comment: @juunas yes, I registered my app accordingly to guide. To be honest I have read a lot of different manuals about registering app. I successfully made authorization for single-tenant but I would like to any of users to connect with my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you please have a check you enabled personal Microsoft accounts to login your multi-tenant app ?

You can check the config here : Please take a look below

[image]

If you enabled multi-tenant users to login only , you should enable personal Microsoft accounts manually .For now, we should modify it in Azure AD App manifest,modify the value of `signInAudience` to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` will make this happen: See the screen shot below

[image]

This change will take few minutes to work.

Comment: can you help me please with one more question? I am making successful authentication, receiving access_token and refresh_token but it seems that access_token is not correct as I do request and it responds with 401 error Unauthorized. My access_token looks like "access_token":"EwBYA8l6BAAURSN/FHlDW5xN74t6GzbtsBBeBUYAAegFpPNhedMjbytXuX32bDod4dOgeX14oj0nTat1dFioBzA1Uz48HBfj9UPlpH5o+wEW....". Isn't is should start with 'eyJ....' and so on? Or I am wrong with something else?

Comment: It does not allow me to change this value in the manifest - had to re-register a new app.

Comment: I'm having this problem

It's telling me this: `Failed to update emailApi application. Error detail: Property accessTokenAcceptedVersion is invalid. [CwKPbN8bkpoCz2mxb4S/Ld]`
with the `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,` as it was by default.

Comment: That doesn't work.   I get 'Failed to update WebApp_MultiTenant_v2 application. Error detail: Property accessTokenAcceptedVersion is invalid. [Bvw18VAXZqGETUepQCsA8P]'

Comment: Not sure, hows your other configuration, it would be great if you can share those details.

Comment: Thanks alot! You saved solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to know that, this very solution still in help resolving problems.