# Interactive Browser Credential "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead."

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-identity, azure-sdk-js

I am attempting to implement Interactive Browser Credential with Azure Identity (JS) in my app so that users can authenticate to their own Azure accounts for my dev tool. I got advice that app registration in Azure AD would be required on a Reddit thread (https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/smcl15/azure_identity_sdk_js_how_to_authenticate_to/). [I have now done so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msrwk.png)

I have registered localhost:8083 and localhost:8085 as redirect URIs and selected the option to allow Account in any organizational directory. However, I am still getting the error "You can't sign in here with a personal account. Use your work or school account instead." Every answer([Access with personal account to multi-tenant application AAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007863/access-with-personal-account-to-multi-tenant-application-aad)) I have read on the topic says that I need to set    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" in the manifest. However, that is how my manifest already is and has been since the beginning. How do I fix the error?

Comment: Further info here on this bug: When I use a personal account, I get the above error. However, when I use an organization account, I instead get a different error:
"ERROR. Scopes: https://management.azure.com/.default. Error message: invalid_client. AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: 480eb9fb-36f6-4381-92f6-af4b9e3bf1d7(Opal). Resource value from request: https://management.azure.com. ..." I tried assigning more permissions, but I get the same.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur in one of the below two scenarios.

**1.** **Resource being different from client application**

Please ensure the request resource is added to the applications required API permissions and the resource API has been consented to .Resource for which you want an access token, you can pass either the Resource URI of a Web APP, or the client Id of the target Web API.  It's important to note that the token  contains the resource as requested (audience).

If you have a permission something like user_impersonation, try by giving scope as https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation

[image]

Please check if you need to add api version as query string as per  [Azure REST API reference documentation | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#request-uri).

Make sure you see the app in the app registrations >all applications blade while Searching for the appId present in the error provided.

**2:** **Resource and client  is the same app registration**

In app registrations ,after exposing the api and adding permissions and scope, Ensure the app has been consented to permission.

For example:
[image]

Comment: That is likely what is causing this. Looking through the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) I still have a lot to learn about how to set the correct app permissions for this use case. I will go back and try to implement what you suggested later. For the product launch, I think we are just going to use the Azure Cli Credential. Thank you.

Comment: @kavyaS Can you please provide more information and images of the terms that you using. What is application in this context? The app in the browser? What is the resource? What is the client? what is the tentant? The Docs are absolutely horrific for this.